# TypeError: Failed to construct 'PasswordCredential': 'id' must not be empty

Tags: javascript, web, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, credential-manager

I want to implement credential management API in my angular app

my login.html looks like this

```html
<div id="login-form" data-ng-form="loginForm" data-ng-controller="LoginFormController">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" data-ng-model="loginCredentials.username" id="uid" autocomplete="username">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" data-ng-model="loginCredentials.password" id="pwd" autocomplete="new-password">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="loginButton" data-ng-click="login()">{{'label.button.login' | translate}}</button>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-show="authenticationFailed">
        <p>{{authenticationErrorMessage | translate}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have LoginFormController as my Controller. Inside the function i created new object called PasswordCredential like this

```js
            var form = angular.element('#login-form');
            //console.log(form);
            var cred  = new PasswordCredential(form);
            //store the credentials
            navigator.credentials.store(cred)
            .then(function(){

            });
```

But i am getting the error PasswordCredential : id must not be empty

Help please

Comment: [PasswordCredential](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PasswordCredential/PasswordCredential) lists the required and optional fields for this API.  If you're going to jam the result of a HTML form into that API you need to have the right field names.  Otherwise you should construct an intermediate object with the right field names, inserting data from the wrong field names of your form.

Comment: Hi James, Can you explain me in detail, i am a beginner :)

Comment: I've never done this either, I suggest you start with the sample form on the Mozilla website.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing the form style

```
var form = angular.element('#login-form');
var cred  = new PasswordCredential(form);
//store the credentials
navigator.credentials.store(cred)
   .then(function(){

   });
```

Pass in the PasswordCredential Object Style

```
var cred  = new PasswordCredential({
                id: scope.loginCredentials.username,
                password: scope.loginCredentials.password
            });
//store the credentials
navigator.credentials.store(cred)
                .then(function(){
                    console.log("Done Saving Creds");
                });
```

And this should be all for saving your credentials!